# Does Xubuntu Include Proprietary Software?

Tags: xubuntu, package-management

I am interested in installing Xubuntu 14.04 on my computer, but I was wondering whether or not it comes pre-installed with copyrighted proprietary software such as codecs, Flash, drivers, etc.?

I know you can install them through the ubuntu-restricted-extras package, or by checking "Install Third-Party Software," but I know some of the Ubuntu family includes codecs and things by default. So, my question is, does Xubuntu come with codecs/proprietary software other than the ones in restricted-extras or through the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No version of Ubuntu includes proprietary software, at least not in essence. Proprietary software included are modules for certain graphics cards and wireless adapters but nothing else. You wont find codecs nor plugins, as they go against the distribution policies of said packages.